# Oracle: ETL and data conversion

Tags: oracle, excel

I have Excel file. It's cell contains number 80035477. After loading it (using private third party application) into Oracle database 80035477 becomes 8.0035477E7 (column(varchar2)). Why this conversion? Sorry for not using search because I don't know exact terms in English for this problem. Not sure if this is called even data conversion (no usable search results).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The conversion is most likely being done by your "private third party application". What is the name of the application?

Comment: I know that it's third party application. Is it some special format constant causing this conversion? For example, pseudo code: to_varchar2(80035477,'UTF-8') causes 80035477 become to 8.0035477E7 because of UTF-8. This third party application is not for widespread use and doesn't even have a name.

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't cause a number to be displayed in scientific notation. Your application is causing the conversion before Oracle gets it.

Comment: Now I got it. It is called scientific notation: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Data-Type/TOCHAR12345679999999EEEEscientificnotation.htm

Comment: Yep, so your application must be doing this when inserting the data into Oracle. It is not likely that it's the database causing the conversion.

Comment: Oracle 'gets' scientific notation, so a TO_NUMBER(column) will convert those 'E' numbers to regular numbers

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Datajam, that your "third party application" is doing that conversion.

How is that cell formatted in Excel?

If that is formatted as a number this could be the reason. Try formatting the cell as a text to avoid that the "third party application" converts the contents to a number.